# What's the difference between Maven compile phase and plugin goal?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm learning about Maven and I try to understand the difference between lifecycle and plugins. For example I have a very simple Maven project like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!! ");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.capitalize("hello world"));
    }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>auto-clean</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I use this command: `mvn compiler:compile`, it creates the target folder and in the HelloWorld.class I see this: `Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 55.0 (Java 11)`. So it is using Java 11.

Now if I change the Java version in the pom.xml to 1.8 and use again the command `mvn compiler:compile` I see the message: `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`. And in the target folder, the HelloWorld.class has: `Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 55.0 (Java 11)`. So it shows Java 11 after I changed it to 1.8 in the pom.xml.

And after that, if I use the command `mvn compile`, first it uses the `maven-clean-plugin (auto-clean)`, then `maven-resources-plugin (default-resources)` and then `maven-compiler-plugin (default-compiler)` with the message:  `Changes detected - recompiling the module!`. And in the target folder, the HelloWorld.class has: `Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8)`. So now it uses Java 8.

So I don't understand why if I'm using the command `mvn compiler:compile` it doesn't uses the `auto-clean` added by me in the pom.xml. But if I'm using `mvn compile` it uses the `auto-clean`. Could somebody help me to understand?

And also I don't understand why if I use the command `mvn clean`, it uses the `default-clean`. But if I use the command `mvn compile`, it uses the `auto-clean`. Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between phases and plugin goals is that phases are groups of different plugin goal executions.

Note that all phases that are in lifecycle before the currently are executed as well, i.e. executing `compile` phase also causes `validate`, `initialize`, `generate-sources`, `process-sources`, `generate-resources` and `process-resources` to run.

---

When you directly specify plugin goal on command line, you run it ignoring the whole lifecycle.